# What are the default margins for the html heading tags (<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, etc.)?

Tags: html, css

I avoid using the defaults with the reset code below:

```
margin:0px; and padding:0px;
```

For example, what are the default margins for the heading tag below?

```
<h1>Header</h1>
```

Comment: Gee I thought you were referring to the HTML5 `<header>` element.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's different regarding which browser, thus if you want a pixel-perfect design then practice is to "reset" those values to 0 (margin and padding) and set them yourself.

"CSS reset" is very common to front-end developers, a simple example of one i use :

```
html,body,blockquote,code,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,pre{margin:0;padding:0}
button,fieldset,form,input,legend,textarea,select{margin:0;padding:0}
fieldset{border:0}
a,a *{cursor:pointer}
div{margin:0;padding:0;background-color:transparent;text-align:left}
hr,img{border:0}
applet,iframe,object{border:0;margin:0;padding:0}
button,input[type=button],input[type=image],input[type=reset],input[type=submit],label{cursor:pointer;}
ul,li{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
strong{font-weight:bold;}
em{font-style:italic;}
```

Comment: This is bad practice. CSS resets have changed over the years, and any blogger claiming to post the ultimate CSS reset will... just have to post another ultimate CSS reset ;) when browsers or namespaces change. Also, CSS resets like these change the desired properties of virtually every element on the page. This is important to realize.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson so what is the better or best practice according to you? To constantly keep updating the CSS resets code?

Answer (score 12):

The CSS specification has an informative [Appendix D. Default style sheet for HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html).

Although it is *informative* it still says:

> Developers are encouraged to use it as a default style sheet in their
>   implementations.

There you can find

```
h1              { font-size: 2em; margin: .67em 0 }
h2              { font-size: 1.5em; margin: .75em 0 }
h3              { font-size: 1.17em; margin: .83em 0 }
h4, p,
blockquote, ul,
fieldset, form,
ol, dl, dir,
menu            { margin: 1.12em 0 }
h5              { font-size: .83em; margin: 1.5em 0 }
h6              { font-size: .75em; margin: 1.67em 0 }
```

Answer (score 10):

### Your Question:

It varies between browsers. Check each browser's specific default stylesheets to tell.

For Google Chrome for example, it's `0.67em`.

---

### A Better Solution?

Do know that if you wish to aim for x-browser consistency, you'll have to use a [CSS Reset](http://www.google.com/search?q=css%20reset).

The most common one being:

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

Although other (and probably better) exist.

Comment: Dont use the "*" solution. Its bad practice and has performance issues.

Comment: I've never faced any performance issues with it. Also, any normal (and by normal I mean < 15 years old), should run this on a very large page without any problems.

Comment: For Firefox it seems to be about `1.35em`.

Answer (score -3):

I think you should set `line-height:100%` for `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6` tag. So blank line will be shortest.

Comment: good typography disagrees . line-height ideally is 1.5em for text and between 1.2 and 1.5em for headers