# Gap Between Two Div's in One page web site

Tags: html, css

I am Trying to create this One page containing different divs with 100% width.

But, when I insert a 'h2' at top of div, itcreates gap between two div's.

assigning top margin removes this gap, but I want the 'h2' at top only.

here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0p8ogdb/)

HTML:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.mainDiv {
  height: 500% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.page {
  height: 20% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center;
}
#headerDiv {
  height: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #7f4c76;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#div1 {
  padding-top: 5%;
  background-color: #334960;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: #f17c72;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: #32ac97;
}
#div4 {
  background-color: black;
}
#div5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
h1 {
  color: #E6E6E6;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif", Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 300%;
  text-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
h2 {
  color: #E6E6E6;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <div id="headerDiv">
    <h1>CSS3 Demo </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="div1" class="page">
    <h2>Text Effects Demo</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="page">
    <h2>Transition Demo</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="div3" class="page">
    <h2>Animation Demo</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="div4" class="page">
    <h2>Multiple Columns</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="div5" class="page">
    <h2>Multiple Columns</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please Help.

Edit screenshot added:
[image]

Comment: What gap do you mean? Can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: you can increase #headerDiv padding-top  and increase  height of #headerDiv. and another way to use jqurey

Comment: @roNn23 added screenshot

Comment: @JentiDabhi the problem is not with #headerDiv.. its the gap between #div1 and #div2

Comment: just add margin:0 to your h2

Comment: sidenote: please remove those` !important` tags - they are both redundant and *very* bad practise.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your h2

```
h2 {
margin:0;
}
```

You issue is that your div has a default margin, of which can be overwritten using this styling

Comment: Thank You.. Worked.. may I know the reason?

Comment: @SurajS the h2 by default has a top and bottom margin. so it will automatically push everything up above it. Removing the margin takes away the space it adds at the top. so it wont push anything. I hope this makes sense

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049952/what-are-the-default-margins-for-the-html-heading-tags-h1-h2-h3-etc)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want the `<h1>`from the `headerDiv`to have `margin-top:0px;` if this is what you want then the fix is quite simple:

```
#headerDiv h1 {
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Or if you want it to be only the direct descendants from the `headerDiv` you could do the following:

```
#headerDiv > h1 {
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

Here you can find the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/s0p8ogdb/3/

After seeing the screenshot recently added you can fix this simply by making the `page` class `display:inline-block`, here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s0p8ogdb/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
h2 {
    color: #E6E6E6;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'Signika', sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
    margin-top:0;

}
#div1 h2 {
    padding-top: 1em
}
```