# Is it a good idea to always set *{margin:0;padding:0}? If so, why are the browsers not setting it default?

Tags: css, browser

I've seen many people suggesting setting `*{ margin:0;padding:0;}`. It does prevent lots of unexpected margin/padding on the page.

But if it's first thing we ought to implement every time we create a CSS file, why do the browsers bother to set default element margin/padding other than `0`?

I guess giving a default margin makes sense to elements like `<p>` to keep the paragraph spacing. But again, if we are suggested to put the `*` reset every time, the browsers' default settings don't matter anyway, right?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A `<h1>` in example unfortunately has a browser-specific margins (see [specific to the browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049952)). Setting margin/padding to `0px` is a poor version of [a normalizer](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) that redesign all css to a clean cross-browser design from what you can start to write css that let the browsers render the same style.

Comment: I disagree (and that's why this question should be closed as opinionated). A browser sets the values, and normalizers set it to something else and then the developer sets it a third time and all of this is getting out of hand. My opinion is you should just set it to what you want it to be in the first place and leave it alone and zero is not that value you want.

Comment: @Rob I accept the crtitic and I accept that it is a dirty workaround only. I think the normalizer does some kind of design-abstraction-layer. What are our options? AFAIK we have no control over the built-in css of the browsers. If we inspect the request, we may able to deliver browser-specific css. But this looks like a very individual work for perfectionsim. Rob, you are a perfectionist. I love you, marry me.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no exact answer to your question. But, the most logical reason to put a preset margin and padding is to most likely make webpages automatically more appealing to the user. If you see a website with text right up against the side of a page, it starts to look a little stretched and sketchy. So, to counter this, they set a margin and padding.

Bryce