# h1 with null size in grid layout on firefox

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to use the grid layout to display my elem in a header, in the firefox browser (v 63.0), as well as in chrome (v 70.0.3538.77) and all of them are displaying correctly, except for the h1 which somehow keeps a null size (but is still visible, see screenshot for further details) despite the cell being big enough for him (I've tested by putting it outside of the grid and checking its size.)

Here is the html (in pug)

```
link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous")
link(rel="stylesheet" href="/style/header.css")

header
  h1 3615 MyBlog
  div.innerGrid
      h1 3615 MyBlog
      span.subline Node.js is cool!
      span.admin
          i.fas.fa-cog
          |Administration
```

and the `header.css`

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100px;
}

.innerGrid{
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90%;
    display: grid;
    margin: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 200px auto 200px;
    grid-template-rows: 10px 40px 20px 20px auto;
    grid-template-areas:
            ". . ."
            "title . button"
            ". . ."
            "subline . ."
            ". . .";
}

.innerGrid h1{
    grid-area: title;
}

.innerGrid .subline{
    grid-area: subline;
}

.innerGrid .admin{
    grid-area: button;
}

.innerGrid {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.innerGrid > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And as you can see, the subline and button behave as expected, but the h1 outside of the grid has a size of 38.4px (on my computer), but the one in the grid has a size of 0px (and the cell in which it should be has a size of 40px, clearly superior to 38.4px).

**edit :** adding screenshot and borders in css to show the problem

[image: screenshot to show the problem]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by null size? Which web browser are you using for this?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Please specify browser. In Chrome it works.

Comment: I'm using firefox

Comment: @JonathanSimonney If you're on the latest Firefox you shouldn't have to prefix it, otherwise that could be the problem, especially if you're browsing in IE. I created a codepen here: https://codepen.io/perjo927/pen/bmZLOQ , that works for me in the latest Firefox

Comment: just checked (and upgraded firefox to v63.0) and I have the same problem on your pen. The h1 in grid is the only elem where border is collapsed and not around elem.

Comment: Thanks, then I misunderstood. I see what you mean now, the cell isn't occupying space, but the text itself is visible for you right?

Comment: OK, just saw your picture, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I see text, but it is beyond cell, and not in cell (whereas all other elems are in cell). (And thank you for your help)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182667/discussion-between-jonathan-simonney-and-programmerper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely comes from the h1 having a default margin set by the browser, and therefore not behaving like your span which doesn't have any. It is common practice to reset the default margin and padding, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049952/what-are-the-default-margins-for-the-html-heading-tags-h1-h2-h3-etc). In your case, you could also simply reset the margin for this specific element, like so:

```
.innerGrid h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```