# Spacing irregularities in html

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I'm trying to format text in html, but there's random spacing that wont go away. I tried fixing padding and margins, but that didn't do anything to help.

I'm new to web dev so I'd appreciate some help and guidance!

Here's my code:

```html
<center> <h2> Hello! </h3>  </center> 
    <h4 style="left: 10px; padding-left: 10px; margin: 0px"> Some thing goes here </h5>
    <h6 style = "right: 90px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px"> test </h6>
    <h6 style = "padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 20px; font-style: regular;"> description </h6>
```

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049952/what-are-the-default-margins-for-the-html-heading-tags-h1-h2-h3-etc

Comment: if you are in chrome, use the inspect feature. even in your snippet, you can see the problem.

Comment: You playing around with margin and padding for those `h` tags and also the syntax are wrong, for an instance `<h2>`...</h4>` closed by `h4`. Can you let us know what you want to acheive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend using Chrome's inspect feature (called DevTools) which opens a new window that provides client side coding that makes developing much easier!

---

As a brief summary, with DevTools, you can:

- modify how the site looks and interacts with users in real time (`Elements` tab). This is client side only (HTML, CSS, JS, etc). CSS is on the right side by default. You can modify code such as CSS to meet your needs which you can then save to your development files.
- check JavaScript output. This is great for debugging your JS by using `console.log()` or checking things like JSON output which will be broken down in an understandable, collapsible view (`Console` tab).
- locate internal/external references like pictures, .js, .css, etc which you can modify/debug in real time. Notable: When viewing something like a .js file where the data is minified, click the `{}` in the bottom left which will `pretty-print` it and make it more legible.
- There are other features but these are going to be best for you for now.

---

This will align the columnar text. The only change was `padding-left: 20px;` to `padding-left: 10px;`.

```html
<center> <h2> Hello! </h3>  </center> 
    <h4 style="left: 10px; padding-left: 10px; margin: 0px"> Some thing goes here </h5>
    <h6 style = "right: 90px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px"> test </h6>
    <h6 style = "padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 20px; font-style: regular;"> description </h6>
```

Alternatively, if you are trying to get rid of the space before / after the `description`, you need to add `margin: 0px;` like so:

```html
<center> <h2> Hello! </h3>  </center> 
    <h4 style="left: 10px; padding-left: 10px; margin: 0px"> Some thing goes here </h5>
    <h6 style = "right: 90px; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px"> test </h6>
    <h6 style = "margin: 0px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 20px; font-style: regular;"> description </h6>
```

Comment: hi! Sorry, I meant the space between "test" and "description" for example, and the space between "Something goes here" and "Hello"

Comment: Hi. Don't be sorry. I've edited my answer to include both since your post didn't specify :)