# How to reduce space between HTML elements in the same div

Tags: html, css

How do I reduce space between elements in the same div (3 elements in 1 line)? I tried to reduce the margin on the left side but that made 4 elements come up in each line.

**Full code** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/jsontestyyy?file=styles.css

```css
.animal {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background-color: #23213E;
}
```

```html
<div class="animal">

  <div class="olay" onclick="location.href='book.html?book=${index}';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div id="mydiv">

      <h2 class="pet-name">${pet.name}

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: do you want 3 animals to be on 1 line?

Comment: You have an invalid HTML markup. You miss a `</h2>` closign tag and have more `</div>`closing tags then you have opening tags. Beside of that. You proberly mean the white-space caused by the header. You can adress it with: `h2 { margin: ... ; }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the default margins for the html heading tags (<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, etc.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049952/what-are-the-default-margins-for-the-html-heading-tags-h1-h2-h3-etc)

Comment: Yes i want 3 animals to be on 1 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have 3 items in a row you can use FlexBox:

> #app is your parent div
> and animals are as childs

```
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.animal {
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #23213e;

  margin: 20px 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

flex is 25% because we want to add margin between each two animals.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this CSS, it may be helpful for you:

```
.animal {
    width: calc((75%-40px)/3);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  #app {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Here is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaBut.png)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set max-width in order to make 3 animals to be on 1 line, i altered some of your css to fix this issues.

```
#app {
  max-width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
}
 .animal {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 15px;
    /* float: left; */
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* margin-top:30px; */
    /* margin-left: 300px; */
    background-color: #23213e;
  }
```